# How to Re-run Razor Code without reloading the page

Tags: razor

I have a web page that displays a message like this: `<marquee>@msg</marquee.`

Then there's an `<iframe>` that displays some Reporting Services reports.

`@msg` is "calculated" when the page loads by querying a table with Razor code inside the `@{}` block.

My question is: since the content of that table can change, how do I "recalculate", or, in other words, re-run that Razor code every, say, 5 minutes, or every time the `marquee` finishes scrolling.

Comment: you should work with ajax and change the content you needed, could be the a partial view with html or json and just replace the inner html on tag <marquee>

Comment: Sorry, this Ajax and Json is above me. Isn't there a simpler thing like a loop, a function, or something like that?

Comment: HTML is a stateless, if you wanna add, edit or change something without do a postback you must do it with javascript and ajax to communicate with the server

Comment: Yes, with plain vanilla JavaScript would be great. I've been googling to see if I can call a Razor function defined in a `@functions{}` block from JavaScript, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: you never can execute razor block statement cuz that's execute on the server before send the page to the client... you must use a partial view in the most simple solution

Comment: Hey Zach, you're right. It's so obvious now! Sorry. Well, you realized I'm new to this stuff, and thanks for your patience. Could you give me a link or two that will get me started with this partial view / Ajax thing? I mean, I just googled it, but there's so many things and I can't tell what is for a total beginner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the post is quite old, but I just discovered it looking for something similar. I used partial views to implement how the marquee gets its data refreshed.

Then, in the page where the marquee is displayed, I'm using java script setInterval function with a defined refresh rate, and I'm calling the method from the controller responsible for populating the marquee with data.

```
$.get("@Url.Action("MarqueeNewsPartial", "Overview", new { siteGUID = @ViewBag.siteGUID   })", function (data) {            
            $('#newsResults').html(data);
        });
```

newsResult is the div where the marquee is generated.

Comment: Is that jQuery? I have to start learning that stuff soon! Thanks for offering your solution.